# Get Mailbox instance Actor in Akka framework

Tags: java, scala, akka

My purpose : get list of messages in Mailbox.

I have created own Mailbox and configured BalancingDispatcher. For this kind of dispatcher one Mailbox is used. I need monitor this messages in queue. But I can't get mailbox. Please suggest.

Comment: You might want to give this a read. http://letitcrash.com/post/17707262394/why-no-mailboxsize-in-akka-2

Comment: Of course you can use a global Object with a ConcurrentHashMap[ActorRef, Mailbox], add an entry in create() method of the Mailbox, remove it in cleanUp() method of the Mailbox and get it from the Actor (or from any part of your app which can cause a lot of bugs/troubles). It will require full thread safety on all levels (in the Object and Mailbox implementations) which can heavily impact the performance. So, if you can avoid doing this - please avoid (see the details in the link @cmbaxter already mentioned).

Comment: Sure you could implement an Observer-like actor monitoring other actor's messages upon arrival using a composable partial function. Reaching out for the mailbox in Akka is bad practice.

Comment: @cmbaxter yeah, already seen this. finally there mentioned that I need custom mailbox and I already implemented this, but how make access still unclear. Something like ConcurrentHashMap worry me by safety reason as mentioned about this. I'm wondering if no "regular" solution :(

Comment: If you are just looking for size, then you might consider adding an extension of `MessageQueue` where you override enqueue and dequeue to add in logic for incrementing/decrementing an atomic int counter.  Then expose this counter via jmx maybe.  Asking the queue for it's current size could potentially force the full iteration of the queue in order to establish that metric and doing that repeatedly would be bad for the throughput of the system.

Comment: @Tioma Did you find any way to access methods of message Queue??